# How to extract specific items from a data frame column and use them as labels for the remaining items?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame with only one column which I would like to extract certain items and turn them into a separate column to be used as a label for the other remaining items. It's a bit hard to explain, if for example what I have is:

```
pd.DataFrame({'Fruits': ['Apple', 'Gala', 'Fuji', 'Grannysmith', 'Honeycrisp', 'Golden', 'pink', 'Orange', 'blood orange', 'Mandrin', 'Tangerine', 'Clementine', 'Banana', 'baby', 'manzano', 'burro']})

          Fruits
0          Apple
1           Gala
2           Fuji
3    Grannysmith
4     Honeycrisp
5         Golden
6           pink
7         Orange
8   blood orange
9        Mandrin
10     Tangerine
11    Clementine
12        Banana
13          baby
14       manzano
15         burro
```

But what I'm trying to convert it into is:

```
    Fruits  Types
0   Apple   Gala
1   Apple   Fuji
2   Apple   Grannysmith
3   Apple   Honeycrisp
4   Apple   Golden
5   Apple   pink
6   Orange  blood orange
7   Orange  Mandrin
8   Orange  Tangerine
9   Orange  Clementine
10  Banana  baby
11  Banana  manzano
12  Banana  burro
```

How would I transform the 1st data frame into the 2nd? I feel stump by this, especially when there can be many categories of fruit and their respective types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First is necessary define fruits in list, then create new column with repeating fruits by [`where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.where.html) with [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) for missing values and forward filling, then remove same values in both columns by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and last set new columns names:

```
L = ['Apple','Orange','Banana']

df['a'] = df['Fruits'].where(df['Fruits'].isin(L)).ffill()
df = df.loc[df['a'] != df['Fruits'], ['a','Fruits']]
df.columns = ['Fruits','Types']
print (df)

    Fruits         Types
1    Apple          Gala
2    Apple          Fuji
3    Apple   Grannysmith
4    Apple    Honeycrisp
5    Apple        Golden
6    Apple          pink
8   Orange  blood orange
9   Orange       Mandrin
10  Orange     Tangerine
11  Orange    Clementine
13  Banana          baby
14  Banana       manzano
15  Banana         burro
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd build a dictionary mapping with some standard logic then use it with Pandas operations

```
fruit_classes = ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Banana']

last_class = None
fruit_map = {}

for fruit in df.Fruits:
  if fruit in fruit_classes:
    last_class = fruit
  elif last_class is not None:
    fruit_map[fruit] = last_class

df.assign(Types=df.Fruits, Fruits=df.Fruits.map(fruit_map)).dropna()

    Fruits         Types
1    Apple          Gala
2    Apple          Fuji
3    Apple   Grannysmith
4    Apple    Honeycrisp
5    Apple        Golden
6    Apple          pink
8   Orange  blood orange
9   Orange       Mandrin
10  Orange     Tangerine
11  Orange    Clementine
13  Banana          baby
14  Banana       manzano
15  Banana         burro
```

---

Alternatively with a comprehension

```
fruit_classes = ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Banana']
```

fruit_classes = ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Banana']

```
pd.DataFrame(
    [[x, None][::(x in fruit_classes) * 2 - 1] for x in df.Fruits],
    columns=['Fruits', 'Types']
).assign(Fruits=lambda d: d.Fruits.ffill()).dropna()

    Fruits         Types
1    Apple          Gala
2    Apple          Fuji
3    Apple   Grannysmith
4    Apple    Honeycrisp
5    Apple        Golden
6    Apple          pink
8   Orange  blood orange
9   Orange       Mandrin
10  Orange     Tangerine
11  Orange    Clementine
13  Banana          baby
14  Banana       manzano
15  Banana         burro
```